# How does gcc find as, ld and other binutils executables?

Tags: gcc, binutils

Is their location hardcoded into gcc code or does gcc just call `as` and we must have `as` location in our PATH variable?

And in the latter case, how could we create two completely separate gcc toolchains? I mean, how can we make `gcc-A` invoke `as-A` and `gcc-B` invoke `as-B` if `as-A` and `as-B` are both called `as`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some of the paths (e.g., to `cc1`) are compiled in. Others (e.g., `as`) use normal lookup in $PATH. This can vary depending on the options GCC is configured with.

You can tell fairly easily by running with `strace`, and grepping for `exec|stat`.

```
$ strace -f gcc foo.c -o foo |& grep exec
⋮
[pid 24943] execve("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1", …
```

That is a call to cc1 by a compiled-in path, as you can see from the
lack of looking for it. Its also not in $PATH.

```
[pid 24944] execve("/home/anthony/bin/as", ["as", "--64", "-o", "/tmp/ccCIrcGi.o", "/tmp/ccbw3PkL.s"], [/* 51 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 24944] execve("/usr/local/bin/as", ["as", "--64", "-o", "/tmp/ccCIrcGi.o", "/tmp/ccbw3PkL.s"], [/* 51 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 24944] execve("/usr/bin/as", ["as", "--64", "-o", "/tmp/ccCIrcGi.o", "/tmp/ccbw3PkL.s"], [/* 51 vars */]) = 0
```

That is looking for `as` in $PATH. You can tell because its trying each
location in $PATH in order.

I've omitted a lot of strace output—even with just stat and exec, its
several pages long.

Running `gcc -v` will show you some of the compiled-in paths (as part of the configure line).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know which configuration options define the final behavior? Is there any way to limit gcc to use only /my/path/as and my/path/ld?

Comment: @MichalisVichos: Probably the configure flag `--with-as=/my/path/as` would do that. Appears the configure documentation is available at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html (or of course with `./configure --help`)

Answer (score 4):

**How could we create two completely separate gcc toolchains?**

Compile GCC from source twice, detailed instructions at: [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/52454603#52454603)

Everything is hardcoded and highly coupled as far as I can see, I don't think there is any other decent solution.

**Query the GCC search path**

You can also query the GCC search path with:

```
gcc -print-search-dirs | grep -E '^programs' | tr ':' '\n'
```

sample output:

```
programs
 =/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu/
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/
```

and a specific program with:

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1
```

sample output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/cc1
```

**GCC spec files**

It is wort mentioning that what actually determines the final `cpp`, `ld`, `as` are the "spec" files in the GCC source code, see also: [What are GCC's passes and invoked programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169380/what-are-gccs-passes-and-invoked-programs/31054195#31054195)

Answer (score 3):

There's an ad-hoc option for that: -B*prefix*, quoting gcc docs:

> For each subprogram to be run, the compiler driver first tries the -B prefix, if any. If
>   that name is not found, or if -B was not specified, the driver tries two standard prefixes,
>   which are /usr/lib/gcc/ and /usr/local/lib/gcc/. [...]